# please explain me how this program works?

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

```
def print_prime_1_n(n):
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    prime = True
    for j in range(2, i):
      if i % j == 0:
        prime = False
        break
    if prime:
      print(i)

print_prime_1_n(10)
```

I spent 2 days to figure out this code but i coudn't find a way to figout it out. please explain to me?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

```py
def print_prime_1_n(n):
    # For all numbers from 1 to n+1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        # Assume i is prime until proven otherwise
        prime = True
        # For all numbers from 2 to i (second number used to check if i is prime)
        for j in range(2, i):
            # If i is divisible by j, then i is not prime because it is divisible by a number other than 1 and itself
            if i % j == 0:
                # Set prime to False
                prime = False
                # Short circuit the loop because we know i is not prime
                break

        # If prime is still True, then i is prime and we can print it
        if prime:
            print(i)

print_prime_1_n(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is a naive (or brute force) algorithm that prints all **prime** numbers between 1 and n

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number): A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers

**How does this function works?**

1. We're looping through all natural numbers between 1 and n that we want to check (is it a prime?)
   `for i in range(1, n+1):`
2. By default at the beginning we think that this number is prime

```py
prime = True
```

And if this variable stays **true** after checking, we're printing current number

```py
if prime:
  print(i)
```

3. And the final step is to check for prime

```py
for j in range(2, i):
  if i % j == 0:
    prime = False
    break
```

`i % j` means remainder of division of `i` by `j`
`i` - our current number we're checking
`j` - the number less than `i` by which we are trying to divide

If the `i % j` equals to 0, then `i` is divisible without a remainder by `j`, so our number is composite, not prime, as it has a divisor

Therefore we set `prime = False` and exiting our inner loop with `break` (we don't have to check further)

**Note** that we loop from 2 to i because upper bound `i` is not included, so we're looping between 2 and `i - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(i):
    
    # if I is divisible by any number smaller than it, it is not prime

    prime = True
    for j in range(2, i):
      if i % j == 0: # divisibility check
        prime = False
        break
    return prime

def print_prime_1_n(n):
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    if is_prime(i):
      print(i)

print_prime_1_n(10)
```